# Fasciation start phase

Tags: identification

Does somebody else see a fasciation mutation in the main flower of this plant? I suspect because it is too leafy at the top.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Cannabis sativa, right? C. sativa is known to be in the group of plants that are liable to fasciation (see the [Occurrence section of the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasciation#Occurrence)) so it is certainly possible. Fasciation is usually quite clear, say where you have multiple leaves or flowers fused together into one grossly enlarged unit. A tell-tale sign appears to be that the stem below the inflorescence (hidden in your image) is unusually thickened, perhaps in a flat, 2-D manner where the flower stalks are fused longitudinally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and indeed this is a sativa one.

Comment: Why has the bounty not been rewarded?

Comment: @Rob because it’s tungsten’s prerogative to award it and the bounty period is not over for another seven days. Please be patient.

Comment: @Stephie Why do you assume I was being impatient? I thought bounties were rewarded automatically when an answer was accepted, patience had nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

This *could be* fasciation (and it probably is), but it could also be the result of a late topping. When topped or fimmed late, instead of a splitting in branches, the splitting will become situated inside the bud. Other causes can include damage by insects, birds or other animals, or infection. Causes with a mechanical origin will most often be discernable from a genetic or hormonal cause by the thickening (and possibly striation) of the stalk as Colin mentioned already.

(Oh and uuh, nice bud bruh!)